# WDK build environments versioning

Tags: dll, makefile, wdk

Sorry if I am asking something obvious. I was trying to recompile usermode helper dll for a driver using Windows 7's WDK when I noticed that is distributed with different dll for each OS built using respective os, platform build enviroments. Makefile shows that it only liks agains libraries in SDK_LIB_PATH. I tested WinXp x86 and WinServer2003 x64 on Win7 x86,x64 and they seem to be comatible. Do I need to distribute separate dll for each os platform commbination?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, no.  You must provide separate DLLs for 32- and 64-bit platforms, but unless you want to take advantage of features found only in a certain version of Windows, a driver built for XP will usually work on later versions of Windows.  There are some exceptions; for example, print drivers that display a UI from the rendering DLL will not work on Vista and above.